# Среднее количество строк в день

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

У меня есть вот такая таблица:

```
┌─────────────────────┐                  ┌─────────────┐
│ Время               │                  │ Время       │
├─────────────────────┤                  ├─────────────┤
│ <время> 22 июн 2020 │                  │ 22 июн 2020 │
├─────────────────────┤                  ├─────────────┤
│ <время> 22 июн 2020 │                  │ 22 июн 2020 │
├─────────────────────┤                  ├─────────────┤
│ <время> 22 июн 2020 │                  │ 22 июн 2020 │
├─────────────────────┤                  ├─────────────┤
│ <время> 23 июн 2020 │  Преобразование  │ 23 июн 2020 │
├─────────────────────┤—————————————————→├─────────────┤
│ <время> 23 июн 2020 │                  │ 23 июн 2020 │
├─────────────────────┤                  ├─────────────┤
│ <время> 24 июн 2020 │                  │ 24 июн 2020 │
├─────────────────────┤                  ├─────────────┤
│ <время> 24 июн 2020 │                  │ 24 июн 2020 │
├─────────────────────┤                  ├─────────────┤
│ <время> 24 июн 2020 │                  │ 24 июн 2020 │
├─────────────────────┤                  ├─────────────┤
│ <время> 24 июн 2020 │                  │ 24 июн 2020 │
└─────────────────────┘                  └─────────────┘
```

Мне нужно "отсечь" время, чтобы таблица слева превратилась в таблицу справа. Затем среднее значение из массива кол-ва уникальных ячеек; т. е. тут 3 раза встречается «22 июн 2020», 2 раза «23 июн 2020» и 4 раз «24 июн 2020», результат будет `(3 + 2 + 4) / 3 = 3`.

Как это реализовать? Основная проблема состоит в том, что я не могу пребрать [пробежаться по/перечислить] все элементы таблицы слева, чтобы её преобразовать в таблицу справа.

Comment: Время-дата как записаны? Это действтельно время-дата или все-таки текст? Данные в таблице преобразовать на месте или можно в другом столбце? Преобразование обязательно или оно только для получения среднего?

Comment: @vikttur это действительно время-дата, только с форматом `hh.MM dd mmm yyyy`

Comment: @vikttur преобразование обязательно, иначе почти каждый столбец будет уникальным, а мне нужны именно дни.

Comment: Вы не поняли. Обязательно ли надо преобразовывать НА ЛИСТЕ? Можно ведь обработать в формуле или макросом, без внешнего визуального изменения. Если данные нужо изменить на месте, то только макросом.

Comment: @vikttur мне подойдёт любой способ. конечно, макросы это не то, решения с ними тоже будут приниматься. Желательно без макросов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Без преобразования на листе просто:

```
=СЧЁТ(A2:A8)/СЧЁТ(1/ЧАСТОТА(ПОИСКПОЗ(ЦЕЛОЕ(A2:A8);ЦЕЛОЕ(A2:A8););СТРОКА(A2:A8)-1))
```

Формула массива, вводится `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` (после правильного ввода формула должна обрамиться фигурными скобками)

Comment: с числами работает, но в том-то и прикол, что мне именно с датой. можете отталкиваться от того, что в ячейке с датой записано примерно вот это: "24.06.2020  19:05:00"

Comment: Вы ответили, что в ячейке дата! Приведите данные в порядок. Копировать любую пустую ячейку, выделить диапазон с "датами", `Спецвставка - Сложить`.Дта-время, записанные текстом, преобрзуются в нормальное число. Задать нужный формат ячейки.

Comment: нет, я сказал что там время-дата. *«то действительно время-дата, только с форматом `hh.MM dd mmm yyyy`»*.

Comment: Ну да, это формат НОРМАЛЬНОЙ даты. Вопрос стоял: это дата или ТЕКСТ. Впишите в ячейку 44007, задайте ячейке такой формат даты - получите сегодняшнюю дату с нулевым временем. И это будет ЧИСЛО, а не ТЕКСТ

Comment: всё, я нашёл ошибку: вы должны написать вот так: `=7/СЧЁТ(1/ЧАСТОТА(ПОИСКПОЗ(ЦЕЛОЕ(A2:A8);ЦЕЛОЕ(A2:A8););СТРОКА(A2:A8)-1))`. если делить на 7, то получиться нужное

Comment: Ну да, формула считает количество... Тогда уж `СЧЁТ(A2:A8)`. И не на 7 делить, а 7 на...

Comment: я так и написал :) (я про "И не на 7, а 7 на..."). а всё, нашёл: сперва написал 7 / <...>, а потом <...> / 7 – да я непризнанный гений! :)